# Matlab openfig to existing figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, handle

When in Matlab I use `openfig(filename);` to open a saved figure, it always opens a new window. All the `'reuse'` argument does is not load the file when it appears to already be open. However, I wish to open the file *into a given figure*, and just overwrite its contents. Is there a way to pass a figure handle to `openfig`, or is there another function that would accomplish this?

So in code, what I would like to do is something along the following lines:

```
f = figure;
openfig(filename, 'Figure',f);
```

and then the figure would be displayed in figure `f` rather than having opened a second figure window.

Comment: What behaviour different from closing the old figure and opening the new do you expect?

Comment: Less flickering, mostly. I am going through roughly 500 images and also need to scale them to full screen. Having a single full screen figure, just changing its contents, would be so much easier on my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can arrange something close to what you want with the [`copyobj`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) function. Here is a try with a docked figure:

```
% --- Create sample figure
h = figure;
ezplot('sin(x)');
set(gcf, 'Windowstyle', 'docked');

pause

% --- Replace the axes
clf
g = openfig('test.fig', 'invisible');
copyobj(get(g, 'CurrentAxes'), h);
delete(g);
```

Which gives me a smooth replacement of the axes, without flickering of the figure.

However, I don't know how this would behave with a fullscreen figure, it surely depends on the method you choose. Check also the doc of `copyobj` in detail, it's not copying everything so you may want to use the `legacy` option.

Comment: I still don't understand why Matlab can open png files to a variable and then display the variable to any figure, while with fig files it has to necessarily create a new figure for it. Anyway... thanks for your solution. It gets the job done nicely.